# MySQL- How to extract data from one column that combined all of columns in table

Tags: mysql

I want to extract data from one column that combined all of columns in table. and It works on the `SELECT` method .

```
ID   FirstName   LastName
1      John        Doe
2      Bugs        Bunny
3      Kim        Johnson
```

How do i do to show result as:

```
ALIAS
1
2
3
John
Bugs
Kim
Doe
Bunny
Johnson
```

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a UNION (or UNION ALL) query:

```
select ID as ALIAS from tablename
union all
select FirstName as ALIAS from tablename
union all
select LastName as ALIAS from tablename
```

an UNION query will return distinct values, an UNION ALL all values. If you want to keep the order, you need an extra column:

```
select ALIAS from
(
  select id, ID as ALIAS, 1 as col from tablename
  union all
  select id, FirstName, 2 as col from tablename
  union all
  select id, LastName, 3 as col from tablename
) s
order by col, id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to achieve what you need:

```
SELECT ID FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT FirstName FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT LastName FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this will do it:

```
SELECT ID from TableName
UNION ALL
SELECT FirstName from TableName
UNION ALL
SELECT LastName from TableName;
```

...where you need to replace TableName with the name of table you are getting the data from.